# 'CGRectGetMaxX' has been replaced by property 'CGRect.maxX' swift error

Tags: swift, error-handling

I am creating a mobile game application and I keep receiving the error **'CGRectGetMaxX' has been replaced by property 'CGRect.maxX'** when I am attempting you use the code:

```
if spaceship.position.x > CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea) - spaceship.size.width/2 {

    spaceship.position.x = CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea) - spaceship.size.width/2

}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue... I know it tells me that it is replaced however when I attempt to use the new method it doesn't work

Thanks!

Comment: "when I attempt to use the new method it doesn't work
" what does that mean?

Answer (score 4):

> when I attempt to use the new method it doesn't work

That's your problem.  It isn't a method, it's a *property* defined on a `CGRect` as stated by the error:

> > CGRectGetMaxX' has been replaced by **property** 'CGRect.maxX'

So instead of calling it like this:

```
CGRect.maxX(gameArea)
```

You instead access the `maxX` property of `gameArea` which is of type `CGRect`:

```
gameArea.maxX
```

So your code becomes:

```
if spaceship.position.x > gameArea.maxX - spaceship.size.width/2 {

    spaceship.position.x = gameArea.maxX - spaceship.size.width/2

}
```